# Why without loss of generality $\{f_n\}$ et $\{g_n\}$ are uniformly integrable over $A$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space. We have the following lemma:

> ***Lemma** : (biting lemma)*
>
> Suppose $\{\phi_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that
> $$
> \sup_{n}{\int_{E}{|\phi_n(t)|d\mu(t)}}
> $$
> Then there exists a non-increasing sequence $\{B_p\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(\cap_{p}B_p) = 0$ and for every $p$
> $$
> \{\phi_n\}\text{ is uniformly integrable over } E\setminus B_p.
> $$

Let  $A\in \mathcal{A}$ be a nonnull set. Let $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are two sequences boundeds in $\mathcal{L}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$. I did not understand the following paragraph:

"*Without loss of generality we may suppose that the nonnull set $A$ is such that on $A$ the two sequences $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are uniformly integrable (apply the biting lemma two times: after two
sufficiently small bites there is still a nonnull set left)*"

**My thinking**

*step 1*: By biting lemma, let non-increasing sequence $\{B_p\}$ such that : $\mu(\cap_{p}B_p) = 0$ and for every $p$ $\{f_n\}\text{ is uniformly integrable over } E\setminus B_p$, then $\{f_n\}\text{ is uniformly integrable over } E\setminus X_1$, with $X_1=\cap_{p}B_p$.

*step 2*: By biting lemma, let non-increasing sequence $\{C_p\}$ such that : $\mu(\cap_{p}C_p) = 0$ and for every $p$ $\{g_n\}\text{ is uniformly integrable over } E\setminus C_p$, then $\{g_n\}\text{ is uniformly integrable over } E\setminus X_2$, with $X_2=\cap_{p}C_p$.

Set $X=X_1\cup X_2$; we have $\mu(X)=0$ and $\{f_n\}$ et $\{g_n\}$ are uniformly integrable over  $E\setminus X$. In particular, $\{f_n\}$ et $\{g_n\}$ are uniformly integrable over  $A\setminus X$.

What I wrote is true?